# ASP.NET Exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'apiconnector.com'

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, navigation

As the title suggests, I'm getting the following exception from an ASP.NET page

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'apiconnector.com'

I can however navigate to this address from a browser, so I know it's accessible.

Why can't ASP.NET navigate to this address?

**EDIT: How am I "navigating" exactly?**

Ok so basically I've imported a [WSDL](http://apiconnector.com/API.asmx?WSDL) as a service reference. All I am doing is calling the methods from the service reference. It's the service reference that does the actual navigation.

Service reference configuration contains the following XML

```
  <endpoints>
    <endpoint ... address="http://apiconnector.com/API.asmx" ... />
  </endpoints>
```

Comment: How are you "navigating", exactly?

Comment: try `http://apiconnector.com`

Comment: can you update the question with sample code?

Comment: @Damith, the sample code would only show me calling the methods created from the service reference. It's actually the service reference that's failing. I don't think this is actually a code issue, I think the request is being blocked from Visual Studio.

Comment: I take it you added the service reference via `http://apiconnector.com/v2/api.svc`?

Comment: @TheSolution, no http://apiconnector.com/api.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working, with the help of a colleague. The problem only occurs in specific conditions, in my case, this was on my development machine as part of a company domain. The domain uses a proxy server to manage web requests/responses. It turns out that our proxy server was blocking responses from apiconnector.com *hence the exception*; In addition to that we had to adjust the proxy settings in Internet Explorer as this provides the default settings in Visual Studio too (when configured correctly).

I cannot specify what was changed in terms of the proxy settings, as I stated, I was helped by a colleague; he managed this part of the resolution; However that only solved half of the problem...the exception was still occurring with Visual Studio, however the addition of the following XML to the web.config file resolved everything, and now it works!

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thank you for this knowledge. It was of a great help

Answer (score 0):

Great I have deleted all the files and replaced with the updated vs2015 published file and it start working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can't solved with default proxy enabled setting.
I solved with this configuration. **Don't forget your proxy server port.** Reference [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/318140/prb-error-on-net-client-that-consumes-a-web-service-through-an-http-pr)

```
<configuration> 
   <system.net> 
     <defaultProxy> 
        <proxy 
           proxyaddress = "http://proxyserver:80" 
           bypassonlocal = "true" /> 
     </defaultProxy> 
  </system.net> 
</configuration>
```